# Smart Contract Uploaded with single mint option; did not take into account multiple mints at once

Tags: solidity, ether, metamask, gas, mint

Very simple question with I'm assuming no answer or a difficult to implement answer.

We have a smart contract with a mint function that takes no arguments. It only allows for the minting of one token.

We'd like to allow users to mint multiples of these tokens at one time rather than one by one.

Is there a workaround without having to upload an entirely new contract?

Here is the mint code (scrubbed to be generic):

```
function assembleToken() public {
        otherTokens.burn(msg.sender, assemblePrice);
        uint256 id = maxTokens + newTokensAssembled + 1;
        _mint(msg.sender, id);
    newTokensAssembled += 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you deployed an upgradable contract, the answer is yes, you will need to deploy a new contract since contracts are inmutable.